# Binning_table in BinningProcess does not generate result from DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hellow I work with Optimal Binning and I have to problem to generate `optb.binning_table.build()` because I do not any output and any any error!

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"var1" : ["a", "b"],
               "var2" : ["c", "d"],
               "var3" : [1, 0],
               "var4" : [56, 18]})
```

And code like below:

```
from optbinning import BinningProcess

toob = ["var1", "var2"]
binning_process = BinningProcess(variable_names=toob)
binning_process.fit(df[toob], df["var3"])

for variable in toob:
    optb = binning_process.get_binned_variable(name=variable)
    optb.binning_table.build()
#     optb.binning_table.plot()
#     optb.binning_table.analysis()
```

[image]

`optb.binning_table.plot()` - works - generates result

`optb.binning_table.analysis()` - works - generates result

`optb.binning_table.build()` - does not work! does not give any result or erro.

What can I do to generate result from my optimal binning code to generate binning_table ?

Comment: I rarely use Jupyter. So how about if you try `print(optb.binning_table.build())`

Comment: wow! great it works! it is so simple... I chose your answer as the best bro!

Comment: I posted it as an answer :)

Comment: You can check it out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `print` as well, so:

```
print(optb.binning_table.build())
```

Would work.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `optb.binning_table.build()` returns a `pandas.DataFrame`. This applies to all binning table classes. See docs: http://gnpalencia.org/optbinning/binning_tables.html#optbinning.binning.binning_statistics.BinningTable.build.